# C# append parameter to string

Tags: c#, asp.net, parameters

Currently in my code I am appending my parameter "users" this way:

```
request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\"users\": " + users+ "}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

I have seen other examples in which the parameter can be appended using curly braces, something like this:

```
request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\"users\": " {users} "}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

But that is not the correct syntax, would it be possible someone show me how to append the panelists parameter correctly, using curly braces rather that  (+) sign?

Thank you.

Comment: rule #1 about json: **do not write it yourself.** serialise an object instead. there's enough libraries that do it, and they do it better than selfmade code.

Comment: I guess what you are looking for is     $"{{\"users\": {users}}}"

Comment: What is `users`? Is this also a string containing a serialized json array? If it is not then you should use a serialization library like [json.net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Comment: The previous comments are correct, you should not hand craft JSON; but they do not answer your question. What you are referring to is [`string interpolation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

Comment: Duplicate shows what you trying to achieve ("string interpolation") but as everyone said in the comments you should not build JSON by hand - it is far easier and safer to use proper serialization i.e. using JSON.Net

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is called [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated).

In your case the correct statement should be:

```
request.AddParameter("application/json", $"{{\"users\": \"{users}\"}}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

Note that the curly braces and quotes need to be escaped properly.